# vb.net with ms access database datagrid view can update the quantity

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

how can i update my quantity value inside the data grid view in vb.net? for example i've added the items already in datagrid view but i will add the quantity for the item that is added to the datagrid view? this is my code in changing the value inside the datagrid but it will only change in the first row in the datagrid.

```
Dim index As Integer
Dim newdatarow As DataGridViewRow
newdatarow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
TextBox6.Text = Price
Price = Price * Val(TextBox5.Text) - Val(TextBox6.Text)
newdatarow.Cells(3).Value = TextBox5.Text
' DataGridView1.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox5.Text())
' DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows(0))
a = a + Val(Price)
TextBox2.Text = a
TextBox7.Text = Price * Val(TextBox5.Text)
TextBox5.Text = ""
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Is this within a loop?  Otherwise, your issue is index is always 0, the first result, here `DataGridView1.Rows(index)`.  I suggest a `for each` loop, like `for each row in DataGridView1.Rows`

Comment: If you are working with a database then you shouldn't be touching the grid in code at all. Populate a `DataTable`, bind it to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. You then access the data via the `BindingSource`. The record bound to the selected grid row can be accessed via the `Current` property. If you want to access every row then you loop over the `BindingSource` itself. The items will be `DataRowView` objects. That mean that, to access ever row, you'd use something like `For Each row As DataRowView In myBindingSource`.

Comment: my project is POS inventory system, and the datagrid view is for the item that is extracted from my DB in order to view the product details. for example, i scan  a barcode in my textbox and all the details will automatically display into the datagrid,